# Upright shape of font for text inside <i></i> tags in HTML

Tags: html, css, fonts, italic

The text inside *HTML* tag pair `<i>` `</i>` becomes italic. Is it a way to make a part of it non-italic, revert an upright shape of font? Something like `\textup` command in *LaTeX*:

```
<i>Long italic text <upright>small upright part</upright> italic text again</i>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a tag that reverts font style changes ?

Answer (score 2):

try this, it will solve your problem.

```html
<i>Long italic text <upright style="font-style: normal;">small upright part</upright> italic text again</i>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply define it to work that way:

```css
upright {
  font-style:initial;
}
```

```html
<i>Long italic text <upright>small upright part</upright> italic text again</i>
```

Comment: I have to ask, Why do you have a rainbow hat ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak because it's winter bash and in winter bash you have to wear a hat ;)